# Unable to launch Allegro 5 exe

Tags: c++, visual-studio, allegro5

I'm working on a game in Allegro 5 using Visual Studio. I was able to create an executable file that would run in its folder no matter where the folder was placed on my computer, but I was unable to run it on another computer when I sent the folder and got a popup with the error message `The application was unable to start correctly (0xc00007b). Click OK to close the application`. Currently the executable folder looks like this: 
[image: Executable folder]

The error message is vague, but does anyone have any ideas as to which dependencies might be missing?

Comment: Did you install the Visual Studio runtime redistributables?  If not, do that. They are *required* to be able to run programs built with VS.

Comment: @JesperJuhl the redistributables don't contain the debug runtimes. Those are only included with a compiler installation.You're not supposed to distribute debug builds.

Comment: @PeterT right..

Comment: I used dependency walker and it does look like my exe is 32 bit and finding 64 bit files with the same name. Where should I be looking for the 32 bit visual studio dlls that I need to include?

Comment: @user3726962 You don't include VS dlls. You include the runtime that is installed during the installation.

Comment: @user3726962 it's in `Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\debug_nonredist\x86\Microsoft.VC140.DebugCRT` But honestly, just compile a release version and bundle the official runtime installer.